# Problem in MaskedTextbox using for Persian date input

Tags: c#

In Persia(IRAN), when we want to write a date ,first we write its day of month,for example 18
then we write month of year,for example 6
and then we write its year for example, and the text must be 1367/6/18
I have added a maskedtexbox(RightToLeft=Yes;Mask=00/00/0000) in my form (RightToLeft=Yes;RightToLeftlayout=True)

The data input format is correct but it display the data as 18/06/1367

what is the solution?

Comment: Is there anyone to answer me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your mask to use spaces between the numbers and the slash:

`00 /00 /0000`

This way you can enter the value as before, but the display direction stays the same:

`1367/ 06/ 18`

[MSDN page](http://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/WinFormsAndArabic.aspx) explaining this behaviour

Comment: dear Gimno my mask was 00/00/0000 and the mask you have offer me was 00 /00 /0000 how it is possible?just with a space my problem solved?

Comment: The MSDN page linked in the answer explains it: "The default "Short date" mask contains spaces between the number and the slash ("/"). This is to insure that dates are displayed properly, even when the MaskedTextBox is RightToLeft."